# AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver usage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

What is the usage of the `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`?

I set it like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
    new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

But how can I access it in my `ApiController`s?

`DependencyResolver.Current` is not the `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`, its the MVC version.

`.Current` is available under `AutofacDependencyResolver` but not under `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`. How can I access the web api version in the web api?

Comment: I would recommend you not to do that. Autofac is intended to be used in Dependency Injection manner rather than Service Locator manner. Just use constructor or property injection to get the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

As you showed yourself... use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` to access this resolver, same way as you did when you set it initially (it's a static object can be accessed from anywhere in Web API).

Or, use the request dependency scope - wherever you have access to current request (i.e. in `MessageHandler`):

```
var myservice = request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as IMyService
```

this will resolve `IMyService` using the currently set `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`

Comment: Okay thank you. But this seems only to work with web-hosting. I use self-hosting and i get always null. Or this error: The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available. Is autofac not able to support self-hosting?

Comment: BTW: That is the advantage of the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver. I can set AutofacDependencyResolver and use it aswell. Can the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver do more?

Comment: @user437899 Could you provide details on where you get null and what the method that throws the exception is?

Answer (score 0):

Try the straightforward way: `this.Configuration.DependencyResolver`, where `this` is an `ApiController` instance.